# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect my asp.net web application with sql server but i am getting this error every time

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My SQL Server is also configured and allows remote connections and is running as well in the configuration Manager. Visual Studio throws an error of unrecognized symbol due to '\' in my server name (`.\SQLExpress`). I tried using different names of server like

```
server=DESKTOP-1MQQSA7\SQLExpress
server =.
server=SQLEXPRESS
```

but it is not working at all

[Sql server running server name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS97F.jpg)

[Visual Studio showing the database name = desktop-1mqqsa7\sqlexpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhpuf.jpg)

[Configuration Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tySpU.jpg)

Comment: you can add a "@" sign at the beginning of your connection string.

Comment: The suggested "@" will avoid the need to escape the backslash. Your connection string should be @"Data Source=DESKTOP-1MQQSA7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI". I would have expected the SQL Server Browser service to be listed in SSCM, which is concerning.